# I did not show big drill down button

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, django

I did not show large content drill down button.
I load json file and the content of the file become drill down button's content.But now only small content drill down buttons are shown.json is like

```
{'items': {'---': '---', 
           ‘A’: ‘a’,
            ‘B’: ‘b’,
            ‘C: ‘c’, 
            ‘D’: ‘d’},
 'type1': 
      {
        "---":"---",
        "a1":"a1",
        "a2":"a2",
        "a3":"a3",
        "a4":"a4"
     },
  'type2': 
      {
        "---":"---",
        "b1":"b1",
        "b2":"b2",
        "b3":"b3",
        "b4":"b4"
     },

   'type3': 
      {
        "---":"---",
        "c1":"c1",
        "c2":"c2",
     },

    'type4': 
      {
        "---":"---",
        "d1":"d1",
        "d2":"d2",
        "d3":"d3"
     },
}
```

views.py is

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from django.shortcuts import render
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse

def index(request):
    with open('./data/company_demand.json', 'r') as f:
        json_data = json.loads(f.read(), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

        preprocessed = []
        counter = 0
        for key in ["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"]:
            values = [(i + counter, value) for i, value in enumerate(json_data[key].values())]
            preprocessed.append((key, values))
            counter = len(json_data[key])
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'json_data': json_data}, {'preprocessed': preprocessed})
```

index.html is

```
    <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;">
    {% for i in json_data.items.values %}
            <option>{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% for key, values in preprocessed %}
    <select name="type" id="{{ key }}">
    {% for counter, value in values %}
        <option value="{{ counter }}">{{ value }}-{{counter}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% endfor %}
```

But now this part

```
   <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;">
    {% for i in json_data.items.values %}
            <option>{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

is not shown.Why does such a error happen?How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json_data and preprocessed should be in the same dictionary passed to your template.

Change

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {'json_data': json_data}, {'preprocessed': preprocessed})
```

To

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {'json_data': json_data, 'preprocessed': preprocessed})
```